# Why is heap usage from MxBean different from that in heap dump?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have a java application that seems to be leaking memory but I have not been able to find a way to identify the root cause. And the heap memory usage I had **from MemoryMXBean** seems to be quite off from that I got **from the heap dump**.

According to:

```
((double) memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()) / (1024 * 1024)
```

the heap memory usage over time increases from 55MB at the beginning to 90MB after it has been running for 4 days.

But the heap dump collected at the beginning was 28.7MB and 34MB when it has been running for 4 days.

```
              MemoryMXBean  heap_dump
beginning             55MB     28.7MB
after 4 days          90MB       34MB
```

The application is job based. That means it stays idle most of the time until a daily job kicks in which generates the workload. As it can be seen, the heap memory usage starts at around 55MB, climbs once per day every day, until the application is restarted. At the peak after a few days without deployment, the heap usages could be as high as 110MB.

Following is how the application is started:

```
jdk1.8/bin/java
  -Dpid=29816
  -Dscript=someApp
  -Djdbc.drivers=someDriver
  -Xmx256M
  -Duser.timezone=UTC
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=someTrustStore.jks
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*****
  -XX:+PrintGCDetails
  -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
  -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
  -XX:+PrintGCCause
  -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/output/logs
  -Xloggc:/tmp/output/logs/someApp-gclog
  package.SomeApp
```

I got the heap dump from the server via following command:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=<FILENAME> <PID>
```

My questions are:

1. why the heap usage number from mxbean is not consistent with that in the heap dump?
2. not even the difference between what mxbean says (90 - 55 = 35MB) is consistent with the difference between the number in heap dumps (34 - 28.7 = 5.3MB), why?

The heap dump of the application after started had following information in the heap dump:

```
Used heap dump  28.7 MB
Number of objects   594,867
Number of classes   8,929
Number of class loaders 84
Number of GC roots  2,710
Format  hprof
JVM version 
Time    2:30:45 PM PDT
Date    Apr 8, 2019
Identifier size 64-bit
Compressed object pointers  true
File path   /tmp/20190408_lessThanOneDay_6168.hprof
File length 71,387,808
```

The heap dump of one that has run for 4 days is:

```
Used heap dump  34 MB
Number of objects   677,239
Number of classes   9,162
Number of class loaders 92
Number of GC roots  2,859
Format  hprof
JVM version 
Time    9:00:15 AM PDT
Date    Apr 8, 2019
Identifier size 64-bit
Compressed object pointers  true
File path   /tmp/20190408_4days_19324.hprof
File length 120,467,694
```

Comment: moved the question to stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617443/why-is-heap-usage-from-mxbean-different-from-that-in-heap-dump